# vscode autocomplete and IntelliSense errors with @google-cloud/datastore

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-cloud-datastore, visual-studio-code, google-cloud-sdk

I'm using vscode v1.15.1

there are a lot of errors with the library, when typing the code (no errors at runtime).

It seams like the library code and docs doesn't align with vscode javascript engine.

for example:
a lot of Datastore functions aren't accessible to the autocomplete engine (like runQuery)

some of the functions documentation doesn't fit the function it self (I get an editor error, but the code works just fine)

[image]

this is my `jsconfig.json` file

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "checkJs": true,
        "target": "es2015",
        "module": "commonjs"

    },
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules",
        "**/node_modules/*"
    ]
}
```

as I said, the code works just fine, the only problem is with the editor, and i'ts really annoying